# Retrieving user information from a parameter

Tags: node.js, twitch

I've spent the last few days creating a twitch chat bot for one of my friends however I've come into an issue when creating a command to give a moderator details about a user in the chat. The command should work like this !whois  and then display all their details that would normally be displayed like this:

```
"{ badges: { moderator: '1' },
 color: '#8A2BE2',
 'display-name': 'CoolDisplayName',
 emotes: null,
 flags: null,
 id: '12345678-90ab-cdef-ghij-klmnopqrstuv',
 mod: true,
 'room-id': '123456789',
 subscriber: false,
 'tmi-sent-ts': '1234567890123',
 turbo: false,
 'user-id': '123456789',
 'user-type': 'mod',
 'emotes-raw': null,
 'badges-raw': 'moderator/1',
 username: 'randomname',
 'message-type': 'chat' }"
```

However I get the following error instead:

```
"C:\Users\User\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\commands.js:332
        if ((message.startsWith(".") && !message.startsWith("..")) || message.startsWith("/") || message.startsWith("\\")) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
at client.say (C:\Users\User\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\commands.js:332:22)
at client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Twitch Bot\app.js:37:16)
at client.EventEmitter.emit (C:\Users\User\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\events.js:101:25)
at client.EventEmitter.emits (C:\Users\User\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\events.js:64:19)
at client.handleMessage (C:\Users\User\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:880:38)
at parts.forEach (C:\Users\User\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:959:36)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at client._onMessage (C:\Users\User\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:958:11)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:418:14)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:188:13)"
```

This is the code that I've created to attempt the command, anything sensitive has been redacted as have all un-needed commands.

```
var tmi = require("tmi.js");

var options = {
    options: {
        debug: true
    },
    connection: {
        reconnect: true
    },
    identity: {
        username: "REDACTED",
        password: "oauth:REDACTED"
    },
    channels: ["#CHANNELNAME"]
};

var client = new tmi.client(options);

// Connect the client to the server..
client.connect();
client.color("GoldenRod")

client.on("chat", function (channel, user, message, self) {
    // Don't listen to my own messages..
    if (self) return;

    if (message.startsWith("!whois") && user.mod === true) {
        var input = message.split(' ')[1];
        if (input.count < 2) return;
        client.say("CHANNELNAME", input.user)    
    }
});
```

Comment: you have to assign your message variable somewhere. I guess your message variable is probably the message the moderator typed in the chat. So you'll first have to fetch this text into your message variable before you can use a method on it. Because now it is telling you that your message variable does not yet exist and you can't use a method on something that doesn't exists.

Comment: add console.log(message);

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code, you have this:

```
client.say("CHANNELNAME", input.user)
```

But `input` is a string : `var input = message.split(' ')[1];` so it's normal that `input.user` is undefined.

Comment: This might be a solution to another problem, but this isn't the solution to the error which the asker posted.